# Karma can't load ts files if not explicit

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, karma-runner

in a javascript file (controller.js), I import a **ts** file (service)

```
import {service} from "../../../service";
```

While everything is ok when running project (dev & prod), when running karma I have the following error:

> ERROR in ..../controller.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '../../../service' in
>   'C:\Workspaces....'

If I write the extension it works fine, but here is many place to change.

Is there a way to make karma working as it works in prod and dev?

I'm using: webpack karma and mocha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe its an issue with the `preprocessors` or `files` value at the karma config file.
make sure you pass both JS and TS files threw the typescript preprocessor.